# Using a regex expression from property file in a Mule SFTP file connector

Tags: regex, file, properties, mule, sftp

I have a flow that gets SFTP files filtered by a regex expression. I utilize many of the settings of the SFTP connector using property files. The one setting I have been unable to do this with is the regex pattern attribute inside the *file:filename-regex-filter* element.

This is my what I have for the SFTP connector.

```
        <!-- Get the HiTrack files via SFTP -->
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint name="HiTrackInboundSFTPEndpoint"
            doc:name="Get SFTP"
            user="${sftp.origin.user}"
            password="${sftp.origin.password}"
            port="${sftp.origin.port}"
            path="${sftp.origin.path}"
            host="${sftp.origin.host}"
            pollingFrequency="${sftp.origin.pollingFrequency}"
            fileAge="${sftp.origin.fileAge}"
            responseTimeout="${sftp.origin.responseTimeout}"
            tempDir="${sftp.origin.tempDir}" 
            archiveDir="${local.archive.directory}" 
            archiveTempReceivingDir="${local.archive.receiveDir}" 
            archiveTempSendingDir="${local.archive.sendingDir}" 
            useTempFileTimestampSuffix="true">

            <!-- Use RegEx filter to filter only HiTrack files with within the proper date format YYYYMMdd
                 Range of dates are from 19000101 to 20991231 -->
            <file:filename-regex-filter
                pattern="hitrack_(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_(.*).xml"
                caseSensitive="false" />
        </sftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

I have tried both of the following for the pattern attribute with no success.

```
pattern="#[${regex.filter}]"
```

and

```
pattern="${regex.filter}"
```

My property files contain the values for all those listed and works great except for the regex filter pattern.

The property file for regex.filter is as follows:

```
regex.filter=hitrack_(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_(.*).xml
```

I do not get any errors; it just does not pass any valid files through when using the property expression. It only works when using the regex expression explicitly.

I would appreciate any suggestions or better, solutions, to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading from a spring property, then you need to escape certain characters like \. So try:

regex.filter=hitrack_(19|20)\\d\\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_(.*).xml

Comment: I needed to use two backslashes, \\ to get it to work when in a properties file. So the property file looked like this:

Comment: regex.filter=hitrack_(19|20)\\d\\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_(.*).xml

Comment: Thanks for you help! :)